# in_array if $massive = $insteredname

Tags: php, html

```
<?
$nimi = $_POST['nimi'];
$nimed = $_POST['nimed'];
if ($nimi) {
    if ($nimed) {
        $nimed .= ', ' .$nimi;
    }
    else {
        $nimed = $nimi;
    }
}
?>
<html>
<form method="post">
Sisesta nimi:
<input type="text" name="nimi" size="9" />
<input type="hidden" name="nimed" value="<?= $nimed ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Lisa" />
</form>
<?
$m = explode(', ',$nimed);
sort ($m);
if ($nimi) {
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($m as $nimi) {
        echo "<li>$nimi<br /></li>";
    }
}
echo '</ol>';
?>
</html>
```

E: WHERE DO I PUT IN_ARRAY SO IT WOULD SAY "THIS NAME IS ALREADY THERE INSTEAD OF ADDING IT TO THE LIST"

```
if (in_array($nimi,$m)) {}
```

Comment: I accidentally the whole question :(

Comment: I don't and what you blablabla either. Maybe care to write a real question?

Comment: I tried really hard but I don't know what you want. Please describe your problem properly.

Comment: it makes a lot of scene when you think about it, and even more when you don't think about it

Comment: Of course you have to put `in_array` before you add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from this that $nimi is a single name, and $nimed is the list of names submitted.

If you wanted to ensure the doubled name isn't in the list and still output, you'd check in_array before concatting the name to the list, something along the lines of

```
if($nimi) {
    if($nimed) {
        if(strpos($nimi,$nimed) === false) {
            echo("THIS NAME IS ALREADY THERE INSTEAD OF ADDING IT TO THE LIST");
        }
        else {
            $nimed .= $nimed . ', ' . $nimi;

... snip ...
```

Edit: The first part of the answer sucked. Removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$nimi = $_POST['nimi']; 
$nimed = $_POST['nimed']; 
$added = false;
if ($nimi) { 
    if ($nimed) { 
        $temp = explode(', ',$nimed); 
        if (!in_array($nimi,$temp)) {
           $nimed .= ', ' .$nimi; 
           $added = true;
        }
    } 
    else { 
        $nimed = $nimi; 
    } 
} 
...
if ($nimi && !$added) {
   echo 'Already in array';
}
```